# How do I place a figure around an enumitem environment?

Tags: enumerate, wrapfigure

I have been doing some LaTeX works lately and I have been wondering how can I insert a figure around a list/enumitem environment. Since the wrapfigure package does not work in this environment, I am quite having trouble doing the same layout as shown in the picture below :( I already tried doing the minipage or parbox commands but to no avail. Your help on this one is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you  please post a small, yet complete, code reproducing your problem?

Comment: You can use `wrapfigure` together with `resume` from `enumitem` for the outer list, i.e. the one with labels `I`, `II` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `minipage`, *\includegraphics* needs `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

```
%\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi.} % level 1 item signs
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}} % level 1 item number
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii.} % level 2 item signs
    \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}} % level 2 item number
    \renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii.} % level 3 item signs
    \renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\alph{enumiii}} % level 3 item number
    \begin{enumerate}
       \item one
       \begin{enumerate}
          \item subitem one
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item subitem one
              \item subitem two
            \end{enumerate}
          \item subitem two
       \end{enumerate}
       \item two
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{minipage}\hspace{2cm}
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{image.png}
 \end{minipage}
%\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why not provide some gap between the two `minipage`s? Also, why is the width of the image set using `\textwidth` and not `\linewidth` (which seems more appropriate in this case)? And what about [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for your list adjustments instead?

Comment: If you want to those to be adjustment of all the enumerated lists, move definitions to before `begin{document}`.

Comment: Is `2cm` = `0.2\textwidth`? Why not just `\hfill`?